# Terminfo parser in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, parsing, console, linux

I've written a pretty minimal parser for terminfo files which works as intended. It compiles fine and I've actually setup some tests over [here](https://github.com/agauniyal/termdb/blob/master/test/test.cpp) which pass successfully too. Now I would like to get it reviewed. There are [docs](https://github.com/agauniyal/termdb/blob/master/docs/info.md) too.

*Please skip over long list of enum members (which I've shortened quite a bit for reviewing) and you can read directly the code.*

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace cap {

// NP represents 'Not Present' properties, represented by
// -1 value in terminfo databases. Since uint16_t is unsigned
// we need to represent it by special NP variable
static constexpr auto NP = std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max();

enum class bin {
    auto_left_margin,
    auto_right_margin,
    no_esc_ctlc,
    ceol_standout_glitch,
    eat_newline_glitch,
    erase_overstrike,
    generic_type,
    hard_copy,
    has_meta_key,
    has_status_line,
    insert_null_glitch,
    memory_above,
    memory_below,
    move_insert_mode,
    move_standout_mode,
    over_strike,
    status_line_esc_ok,
    dest_tabs_magic_smso,
    tilde_glitch,
    transparent_underline,
    xon_xoff,
    needs_xon_xoff,
    prtr_silent,
    hard_cursor,
    non_rev_rmcup,
    no_pad_char,
    non_dest_scroll_region,
    can_change,
    back_color_erase,
    hue_lightness_saturation,
    col_addr_glitch,
    cr_cancels_micro_mode,
    has_print_wheel,
    row_addr_glitch,
    semi_auto_right_margin,
    cpi_changes_res,
    lpi_changes_res,
    backspaces_with_bs,
    crt_no_scrolling,
    no_correctly_working_cr,
    gnu_has_meta_key,
    linefeed_is_newline,
    has_hardware_tabs,
    return_does_clr_eol
};

enum class num {
    columns,
    init_tabs,
    lines,
    lines_of_memory,
    magic_cookie_glitch,
    padding_baud_rate,
    virtual_terminal,
    width_status_line,
    num_labels,
    label_height,
    label_width,
    max_attributes,
    maximum_windows,
    max_colors,
    max_pairs,
    no_color_video,
    buffer_capacity,
    dot_vert_spacing,
    dot_horz_spacing,
    max_micro_address,
    max_micro_jump,
    micro_col_size,
    micro_line_size,
    number_of_pins,
    output_res_char,
    output_res_line,
    output_res_horz_inch,
    output_res_vert_inch,
    print_rate,
    wide_char_size,
    buttons,
    bit_image_entwining,
    bit_image_type,
    magic_cookie_glitch_ul,
    carriage_return_delay,
    new_line_delay,
    backspace_delay,
    horizontal_tab_delay,
    number_of_function_keys
};

enum class str {
    back_tab,
    bell,
    carriage_return,
    change_scroll_region,
    clear_all_tabs,
    clear_screen,
    clr_eol,
    clr_eos,
    column_address,
    command_character,
    cursor_address,
    cursor_down,
    cursor_home,
    cursor_invisible,
    cursor_left,
    cursor_mem_address,
    cursor_normal,
    cursor_right,
    cursor_to_ll,
    cursor_up,
    cursor_visible,
    delete_character,
    delete_line,
    dis_status_line,
    down_half_line,
    enter_alt_charset_mode,
    enter_blink_mode,
    enter_bold_mode,
    enter_ca_mode,
    enter_delete_mode,
    enter_dim_mode,
    enter_insert_mode,
    enter_secure_mode,
    enter_protected_mode,
    set_a_foreground,
    set_a_background,
    pkey_plab,
    device_type,
    code_set_init,
    set0_des_seq,
    set1_des_seq,
    set2_des_seq,
    set3_des_seq,
    set_lr_margin,
    set_tb_margin,
    bit_image_repeat,
    bit_image_newline,
    bit_image_carriage_return,
    color_names,
    define_bit_image_region,
    end_bit_image_region,
    set_color_band,
    set_page_length,
    display_pc_char,
    enter_pc_charset_mode,
    exit_pc_charset_mode,
    enter_scancode_mode,
    exit_scancode_mode,
    pc_term_options,
    scancode_escape,
    alt_scancode_esc,
    enter_horizontal_hl_mode,
    enter_left_hl_mode,
    enter_low_hl_mode,
    enter_right_hl_mode,
    enter_top_hl_mode,
    enter_vertical_hl_mode,
    set_a_attributes,
    set_pglen_inch,
    termcap_init2,
    termcap_reset,
    linefeed_if_not_lf,
    backspace_if_not_bs,
    other_non_function_keys,
    arrow_key_map,
    acs_ulcorner,
    acs_llcorner,
    acs_urcorner,
    acs_lrcorner,
    acs_ltee,
    acs_rtee,
    acs_btee,
    acs_ttee,
    acs_hline,
    acs_vline,
    acs_plus,
    memory_lock,
    memory_unlock,
    box_chars_1
};
}


class TermDb {
private:
    int status{0};
    std::string name;
    std::bitset<44> booleans;
    uint16_t numbers[39];
    std::vector<uint16_t> stringOffset;
    std::vector<char> stringTable;

    void resetData()
    {
        status = 0;
        name.clear();
        booleans.reset();
        std::fill(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), cap::NP);
        stringOffset.clear();
        stringTable.clear();
    }

    bool loadDB(const std::string&, std::string);

public:
    TermDb()
    {
        std::fill(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), cap::NP);
    }

    TermDb(const std::string& _n, std::string _p = "/usr/share/terminfo/")
        : TermDb()
    {
        loadDB(_n, _p);
    }

    int getStatus() const noexcept { return status; }
    explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return status == 0; }
    const std::string& getTermName() const noexcept { return name; }

    bool parse(const std::string& _n, std::string _p = "/usr/share/terminfo/")
    {
        resetData();
        return loadDB(_n, _p);
    }

    bool getCapBin(cap::bin _b) const noexcept
    {
        const auto b = static_cast<int>(_b);
        return booleans[b];
    }

    uint16_t getCapNum(cap::num _n) const noexcept
    {
        const auto n = static_cast<int>(_n);
        return numbers[n];
    }

    std::string getCapStr(cap::str _s) const
    {
        const size_t s = static_cast<int>(_s);
        std::string result;
        if (s <= stringOffset.size()) {
            const auto offset = stringOffset[s];
            if (offset != cap::NP && offset < stringTable.size()) {
                result.append(&stringTable[offset]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};


bool TermDb::loadDB(const std::string& _name, std::string _path)
{
    if (_name.empty() || _path.empty()) {
        status = -1;
        return false;
    }

    _path.append(_name, 0, 1).append(1, '/').append(_name);
    std::ifstream db(_path.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (!db) {
        status = -2;
        return false;
    }

    const int size = db.tellg();
    if (size == 0) {
        status = -2;
        return false;
    }


    db.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(size);
    db.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer.data()), size);
    db.close();

    // sanitize if no at-the-end null byte present
    buffer.push_back('\0');

    // header contains a constant magic number
    const auto magic_byte = buffer[0] | (buffer[1] << 8);
    if (magic_byte != 0432) {
        status = -3;
        return false;
    }


    /* size list contains size/numbers of -
      - name [0]
      - booleans [1]
      - numbers [2]
      - offsets [3]
      - stringTable [4]
    */
    uint16_t sList[5] = { 0 };
    for (auto i = 2, j = 0; i < 12; i += 2, ++j) {
        sList[j] = buffer[i] | (buffer[i + 1] << 8);
    }


    // check for malformed databases
    const std::size_t minBytes
      = 12 + sList[0] + sList[1] + ((sList[2] + sList[3]) * 2) + sList[4];
    if (buffer.size() <= minBytes) {
        status = -4;
        return false;
    }

    // parse name of terms
    name.append(buffer.begin() + 12, buffer.begin() + 11 + sList[0]);

    // parse boolean values
    int cursor = 12 + sList[0];
    for (auto i = cursor; i < cursor + sList[1]; ++i) {
        if (buffer[i]) {
            booleans.set(i - cursor);
        }
    }
    cursor += sList[1];


    /*
        Between the boolean section and the number section, a null
        byte will be inserted, if necessary, to ensure that the
        number section begins on an even byte (this is a relic of
        the PDP-11's word-addressed architecture, originally
        designed in to avoid IOT traps induced by addressing a
        word on an odd byte boundary). All short integers are
        aligned on a short word boundary.
    */
    cursor += cursor % 2;


    // parse numbers values
    for (auto i = cursor, j = 0; j < sList[2]; i += 2, ++j) {
        numbers[j] = buffer[i] | (buffer[i + 1] << 8);
    }
    cursor += sList[2] * 2;


    // parse stringOffset values
    stringOffset.resize(sList[3], 0);
    for (auto i = cursor, j = 0; j < sList[3]; i += 2, ++j) {
        stringOffset[j] = buffer[i] | (buffer[i + 1] << 8);
    }
    cursor += sList[3] * 2;


    // move rest of the buffer to string table
    std::move(buffer.begin() + cursor, buffer.end(),
      std::inserter(stringTable, stringTable.begin()));

    return true;
}

/*
 * [1] http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/term.5.html
 * [2] $ man terminfo
 * [3] $ man term
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Class and namespace names

You have a very terse name for your namespace:

```
namespace cap {
```

And inside it you have:

```
class TermDb {
```

So you'd probably have to write `cap::TermDb termdb;` in code using your library. This does not really say that it has something to do with terminfo.
It would be more clear to write something like `terminfo::database termdb`. Perhaps you can adjust your namespace and classes accordingly?

## Function argument names

You are using weird short variable names for function arguments, like here:

```
TermDb(const std::string& _n, std::string _p = "/usr/share/terminfo/")
```

First, it is always better to use long, descriptive names for variables (unless it's something ideomatic, like `i` for an integer iterator). Second, the underscore prefix is normally to distinguish private members from public members. Here it is not necessary, and makes the code more ugly than necessary. I suggest you rewrite it to:

```
TermDb(const std::string& name, std::string path = "/usr/share/terminfo/")
```

## You can use overloading

You have the following function:

```
bool getCapBin(cap::bin _b) const noexcept
uint16_t getCapNum(cap::num _n) const noexcept
std::string getCapStr(cap::str _s) const
```

Since they are all distinguished by the type of argument, you can just give them all the same name. For example:

```
bool getCapability(cap::bin _b) const noexcept
uint16_t getCapapbility(cap::num _n) const noexcept
std::string getCapability(cap::str _s) const
```

## Consider throwing exceptions

When you encounter errors, like when something goes wrong in `TermDb::loadDB()`, you just set the `status` variable and `return false`. It is very easy to ignore the return value in applications using your library. Instead, you could throw an exception (preferrably derived from `std::runtime_error`).

## Check the status of your `ifstream` after seeking and reading

```
db.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(size);
db.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer.data()), size);
db.close();
```

There can be errors when seeking or reading from `db`. You never check for errors. I suggest adding the following after the above lines:

```
if (db.fail()) {
    status = -2;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `cap` namespace denotes capability and `TermDb` class lies outside of it. But I'm going to work on namespace naming for sure. Function overloading is excellent advice, thank you. About the `_`, I've always used them to denote arguments but I agree with naming the variable correctly. About `ifstream`, I wasn't even aware of the fact that I needed to check for `fail()` after the operations, are you sure I should  place that call after `close()` call?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: Ah, I didn't notice the namespace only covered the enums. It's best to put everything in the namespace, I think. I would avoid a namespace called "cap", the name is just too generic. You can call `fail()` after a `close()`. The stream is closed, but the `ifstream` variable is still valid, and the failure status is preserved unless it is explicitly reset. Theoretically, closing can fail on itself. If you are only reading, and all reads succeeded, a fail during `close()` is very unlikely of course, but when writing it can happen.